# UITableView with Year as section and Month as item GIVEN a set of NSManagedObject with NSDate property

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am working on a 'timeline' feature. In my core data I have a set of `NSManagedObject` (Object). each Object has a `NSDate` property (date).

No I want a `UITableView` as the timeline. Each year will be a section and each month will be an item. For example I have three Objects. Their dates are "Nov-2013", "Oct-2013", "Oct-2012". The table view should be like:

```
--2013--

Nov

Oct

--2012--

Oct
```

Because I want this table view to be synced with my database, I want to use fetched results controller. The naive approach I can think of now is to create a 'Date' object in my core data. 'Date' will have a many-to-one relationship with 'Object'. Every time I create an Object I will need to relate it with a Date object. Then I can simply create an `NSFetchedResultsController` by quering this Date object.

I am wondering if there is better solution than the above one? I don't really like the above solution because it requires creating a new object in core data..

Thanks!

-Erben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSFetchedResultsController needs a persistent key for grouping... so if you want to 'sectionize by year, you have to create a year property in your mom.

Answer (score 0):

well i suggest you to first fetch all results from core data and sort your array using comparatorBlock or selectorFunction, such that,
1)split the string into two at'-' using componentSeparator method.You will get a string array of two objects, one month and next year 
2)Now give priority to year first by converting it to integer and matching.
After your array is sorted , now create and call function which store index positions of particular year into an array.
Based on those indexed year array , you can create table.

This is the logic that i want to follow. I will test and upload the code asap.

The final working code below.

```
NSArray *data = @[@"Nov-2013",@"Oct-2013",@"Oct-2012",@"Jan-2012",@"Feb-2012",@"Jan-2013"];
NSArray *monthArray = @[@"Jan",@"Feb",@"Mar",@"Apr",@"May",@"Jun",@"Jul",@"Aug",@"Sep",@"Oct",@"Nov",@"Dec"];
data = [data sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSArray *strArray1 = [(NSString *)obj1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
    NSArray *strArray2 = [(NSString *)obj2 componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];

    NSComparisonResult result =NSOrderedSame;
    NSInteger year1 = [((NSString*)strArray1[1]) integerValue];
    NSInteger year2 = [((NSString*)strArray2[1]) integerValue];
    if(year1>year2)
        result = NSOrderedAscending;
    else if (year1<year2)
        result =NSOrderedDescending;
    else{
        NSInteger month1;
        NSInteger month2;
        for(month1=0;monthArray.count;month1++)
            if([strArray1[0] isEqualToString:monthArray[month1]])
                break;
        for(month2=0;monthArray.count;month2++)
            if([strArray2[0] isEqualToString:monthArray[month2]])
                break;
        if (month1>month2)
            result=NSOrderedAscending;
        else if (month1<month2)
            result=NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    return result;
}];
NSLog(@"%@",data);
/*
(
    "Nov-2013",
    "Oct-2013",
    "Jan-2013",
    "Oct-2012",
    "Feb-2012",
    "Jan-2012"
)
*/
NSMutableArray *indexArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSInteger lastIndex=0,i=0;
NSInteger lastYear =[((NSString *)[(NSString *)data[0] componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"][1]) integerValue];
for (i=1; i<data.count; i++) {
    NSInteger year =[((NSString *)[(NSString *)data[i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"][1]) integerValue];
    if(year!=lastYear){
        NSDictionary *dic =@{@"year":[NSNumber numberWithInteger:lastYear],@"fromIndex":[NSNumber numberWithInteger:lastIndex],@"toIndex":[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i-1]};
        [indexArray addObject:dic];
        lastYear=year;
        lastIndex=i;

    }
}
NSDictionary *dic =@{@"year":[NSNumber numberWithInteger:lastYear],@"fromIndex":[NSNumber numberWithInteger:lastIndex],@"toIndex":[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i-1]};
[indexArray addObject:dic];
NSLog(@"%@",indexArray);
/*
(
        {
        fromIndex = 0;
        toIndex = 2;
        year = 2013;
    },
        {
        fromIndex = 3;
        toIndex = 5;
        year = 2012;
    }
)
*/

Use this arrayof dictionaries to feed data to table.
Hope this HELPS.
```

Comment: you haven read the question I guess.. also: this breaks easily as it doesn't scale at all

Comment: why wouldn't this scale to coredata managed Objects? Let me make the logic clear. Just like i had used string array named 'data'. Get all your managed objects from that particular entity to this data Array and inside the comparator function, get string from date from each managed object.It will now sort the array, similarly modify in the part where i index them to dictionary. That would work. I am eager to help, please let me know my misunderstanding.

Comment: fetch 10000 objects? ;) no sir

Comment: I did this in the past as well.. on osx

Comment: @Daij-Djan: well in that case it might overload the memory.But where in the hell he mentioned that in question.

Comment: please don't step down to swearing -- he EXPLICITLY says that he wants NSFetchedResultsController.. the fact that it doesn't scale (and not only because of memory. I will eat CPU time like crazy) I inferred and it is valid